# Navigate through website without page-reload + url change

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, url, reload

So I've been searching for a while to find myself the solution to the idea.
I've been inspired by this website: http://www.colorz.fr/#!/services/

Navigate through the website and you get the idea of what I want to do right here.
I've been struggling with Ajax for a while, so far I'm able to push and load content in a certain div. But I have no idea how to make it like the website I posted as the example.
The cool thing is, when you remove the #! in the website the pages also excist (for SEO reasons I guess). I tried to mail the company, but without succes sofar.

Can someone guide me through this technique, where should I start with and what should I look for? This example is based on WordPress, but I guess I have to start with loading hardcoded files before I get into the dynamic WordPress part.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look at the HTML5 History API

Comment: The thing is with HTML5 History api = "Note: since these urls aren't real, refreshing the page will land on an invalid url."

Answer (score 0):

Try some JavaScript framework like Ember.js or Backbone.js.
They are made for this. You navigate through the website via JavaScript and interact with server using AJAX to get data or create new content. Good luck.

Edit: I see it's important to you to share URLs, so that when someone lands on some URL it takes him to the exact page you were on. That's Ember.js's specialty.

Comment: I didn't see and ember.js included in the page. I would like to use this feature too.